# oracle bulk update

Tags: oracle

Is there any solutions to make bulk update for oracle? After researching didn't found any related topic to my question but let's see, having following query

```
UPDATE USERS SET(NAME) = CASE
WHEN ID = (1, 2) THEN('NAME1', 'NAME2') end where ID IN (1, 2);
```

Having the following exception - `ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL`

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: "What I'm doing wrong here?" -- you are violating the CASE expression syntax rules.

Comment: Understood, is there any other approaches that I could deal with bulk update? I would like not to use update approach with temporary tables or creating multiple `case - then` statements for each Id, is at allowed somehow?

Comment: Your use of "bulk update" is unfamiliar to me. Can you explain, using some sample data, what exactly you are trying to achieve? Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Are you "bulk updating" only two rows? Or a random number of rows?

Comment: @MichaelKutz It would update a random number of rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error with your case expression, I would guess you want

```
UPDATE USERS 
SET NAME = CASE ID WHEN 1 THEN 'NAME1'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'NAME2' end 
where ID IN (1, 2);
```

If you want to handle a large amount of different keys and values then you could use one statement with bulk binds (array binds), the coding of this will depend on the driver you are using but it will look something like

```
statement='update users set name = :name where id = :id';
binds = array of names, array of ids;
execute(statement, binds);
```

In general, this will perform similarly to the previous approach. The previous approach is favourable if this is a one off.

You could also load a staging table with `id,name` pairs from a flat file with SQL*Loader and then use a merge statement

```
merge into users u
using staging_users su
on (u.id = su.id)
when matched then update
set u.name = su.name
```

Comment: Well, I know I could go this way, but instead I was trying to ask if there a possible way to pass an array of ids = values instead of making multiple copy of `when -> then`

Comment: Have you tried `decode`? That syntax is a bit shorter: `set name = decode(id,1,'NAME1',2,'NAME2')`

Comment: @semperfi That still wouldn't be a "bulk update", though. It seems you are asking for a way to pass array arguments to a `case` expression. That isn't part of its syntax, so you can't. You could write a function to do that, though.

Comment: I've added some alternative ways of doing this that you might consider more `bulk update`

Comment: @AndrewSayer a MERGEis not necessary here, an UPDATE statement on a query  will work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59898/1

Comment: @miracle173 I prefer to write using a merge, they achieve the same goal and will have the same performance. The main difference is that the updatable view method (currently) requires the uniqueness to be guaranteed by a constraint so needs an additional pass of the staging table.